# How to iterate through the checkedlistbox and check items?

Tags: c#

I have a check list box bind with some datasource i assigned valueMember to some id?
Now the checkedlist box is binded, i have another datable through which i need to catch each id if some coulmn and want to check it in the checkedlist box item's value member value, if both match the item will be checked. I did following but unable to check the check box.,
Could you help me with this?

```
  private void catCmb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (mode == "EDIT")
            {
                custOptionChkList.DataSource = cDressing.GetAllDressingDetailByCatID(14);
                custOptionChkList.DisplayMember = "Description";
                custOptionChkList.ValueMember = "CatID";
                DataTable dt = objCFreeCust.GetAllFreeCustomizationItem(currProductID, custCmb.SelectedIndex);
                foreach (var ListItem in custOptionChkList.Items)
                {
                    DataRowView drv = ListItem as DataRowView;
                    int id = Convert.ToInt16(drv["CatID"]);
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt16(dr["CustomizationId"]) == id)
                        {
                            //here i need to check the item's check box from checkedboxlist
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `SetItemChecked` method of `CheckedListBox`.

```
int index = 0; //to keep track of each item index
foreach (var ListItem in custOptionChkList.Items)
{
    DataRowView drv = ListItem as DataRowView;
    int id = Convert.ToInt16(drv["CatID"]);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt16(dr["CustomizationId"]) == id)
        {
            custOptionChkList.SetItemChecked(index, true);  //true means set it to checked            
        }
    }

    index++;
}
```

or with `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < custOptionChkList.Items.Count; i++)
{
    DataRowView drv = custOptionChkList.Items[i] as DataRowView;

    int id = Convert.ToInt16(drv["CatID"]);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt16(dr["CustomizationId"]) == id)
        {
            custOptionChkList.SetItemChecked(i, true);  //true means set it to checked
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello can you please try out this..

if you are going with Linq to Dataset then use first method to convert data table to AsEnumerable to query using linq, or just simple use Select method of datatable as shown in second approch.

```
foreach (ListItem item in custOptionChkList.Items)
{
     if (dt.AsEnumerable().Any(row => row.Field<String>("CustomizationId").Equals(item.Value)))
     {
         item.Selected = true;
     }
}
                  OR
foreach (ListItem item in custOptionChkList.Items)
{
     var foundid= dt.Select("CustomizationId = '" + item.Value + "'");
     if (foundid.Length != 0)
     {
         item.Selected = true;
     }
 }
```